# Kivy mp3 player with pygame doesn't stop songs

Tags: pygame, kivy, kivymd

i have a function that i use to stop or play the song like below:

```
class Utils(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.paused = pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()

def ToggleAudio(self):
    if self.paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    if not self.paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    self.paused = not self.paused
```

then i have another one function that i use to set the song playing position if the user moves the trackbar:

```
def SetSongPos(self):
    index = 0
    currentsong = UTILS.CurrentSongname

    for song in songs:
        if song == currentsong:
            MainPlayer.unload()
            MainPlayer.load(song)
            value = self.root.ids.track.value
            MainPlayer.play(0,value)
```

PS(songs is the full list of mp3's paths).

when i call this function the mp3 audio toggler that is inside the class ToggleAudio stops working and when i press the stop button it stops the song for a sec then keep playing it

Answer (score 0):

OK so I created this same project using Pygame in Tkinter 8 month ago .you can get reference from my project.

[check code of m_player.py](https://github.com/mswadile/Python-Music-Player)

I think in your case you have to stop your mixer before loading song

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

Then load mp3 file and then play your song

```
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

and set self.paused to False

I can help better if you share your full code!